# How run single test with parameterized in PyCharm (I use nosetests)

Tags: python, testing, pycharm, nose, parameterized

I have a quick question: can I run one test with parameters by Parameterized? E.g. in PyCharm? I can run all test cases but I don't want to check all cases all the time :)

For example, I have something like that:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
@parameterized.expand(list)
   def test_1(self, item):
       assert_equal(item)
@parameterized.expand(list)
   def test_2(self, item):
       assert_equal(item)
```

And I want to run only "test_1" with "list". Can I do this?